# Python tkinter, not Event error

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

```
Class xy:
 ...
 ...
 ...
    self.btns = []
    for x in enumerate(dates):
        self.btns.append(tk.Button(bf, text = x[1], height = 2, width = 12, command = lambda i = x[0]: self.show_frame(pages[i])))
        self.btns[x[0]].pack(side = "left")
        self.btns[x[0]].bind("<Button-1>", lambda i = x[0]: self.active(i)) # THERE IS AN ERROR

    self.show_frame(pages[0])


def show_frame(self, key):
    frame = self.frames[key]
    frame.tkraise()

def active(self, index):
    self.btns[index].config(relief = "sunken")
```

When I do this, that happen:

```
"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Event"I'm trying figure it out for hour.
```

Comment: Did the error message tell you what line the problem was on? If we knew it might be easier to identify the problem.

Comment: Line with a method active(), `self.btns[index].config(relief = "sunken")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `bind`, tkinter will automatically pass an event object as the first parameter. Even though you're using lambda to set a default for `i`, tkinter always sets it to the event object.

You need to change your lambda to this:

```
lambda event, i=x[0]: self.active(i)
```